# java user snmp4j to get "localhost cpu used rate" and display use Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, snmp4j

I write a code to get localhost cpu used rate.and it succeed!
Now i want to get 60 seconds cpu status and display use Jfreecharts.
I don't know how to get data in 60seconds.
Ask for your help,thank you.

Comment: Use a timer, either `java.util.Timer` or `java.swing.Timer` depending on context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Using JFreeChart to display recent changes in a time series*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513), [_et al_](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20javax.swing.Timer).